# What is Polymorphic encryption?

Tags: encryption

Well i have downloaded some cryptographic algorithm. Do there are those I didn't understand so this is my question: What is polymorphic RC4 or Polymorphic xor encryption?

I heard this in malware encryption.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the context where you heard this? The closest thing I know is polymorphic malware.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are referring to a polymorphic virus?  This is a virus which consists of a decryption program along with the actual virus code which is encrypted.  When the virus runs and subsequently spreads, it re-encrypts itself with a different key, thereby appearing to be different each time it propagates.

Comment: +1 before the question closes. This however seems to be rather different than polymorphic encryption.